# Progress bar for Multipart uploading with multiple files Android

Tags: android, progress-bar, multipart

Edit: solved, scroll down ;)

Following the tutorial [here](http://toolongdidntread.com/android/android-multipart-post-with-progress-bar/),

I implemented a progress bar dialog within an AsyncTask to show the percentage of data uploaded. Currently it is just showing from 0% to 100%, then it gets stuck at 100% until all the data are uploaded. I am trying to upload a Json string plus 4 images.

Code:

```
 private class UploaderTask extends AsyncTask<JSONArray, Integer, String> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    protected Context mContext;
    long totalSize;

    public UploaderTask(Context context) {

        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setTitle("Uploading data");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        //dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        dialog.show();
        //dialog.setProgress(0);

    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(JSONArray... json) {

        String responseMessage = "";
        int counter = 0;

        try {

            CustomMultiPartEntity entity = new CustomMultiPartEntity(new ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void transferred(long num) {
                    publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                }
            });

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

            //convert JSON array to String (first element contains the whole of data)
            String json_encoded_string = json[0].toString();

            //add json data
            entity.addPart("json", new StringBody(json_encoded_string));

            //get all images plus data and add them to the Multipart Entity

            for (images_cursor.moveToFirst(); !images_cursor.isAfterLast(); images_cursor.moveToNext()) {

                counter++;

                //Get image and convert to byte array
                byte[] image_ba = images_cursor.getBlob(images_cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
                long image_unit_id = images_cursor.getLong(images_cursor.getColumnIndex("unit_id"));
                String image_caption = images_cursor.getString(images_cursor.getColumnIndex("caption"));

                //add image to multipart
                entity.addPart("image" + counter, new ByteArrayBody(image_ba, "image" + counter + ".jpg"));

                //add unit _id to multipart
                entity.addPart("image_unit_id" + counter, new StringBody(String.valueOf(image_unit_id)));

                //add caption to multipart
                entity.addPart("image_caption" + counter, new StringBody(String.valueOf(image_caption)));

            }

                            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            responseMessage = inputStreamToString(inputStream);

            //log out response from server
            longInfo(responseMessage);

        }
        //show error if connection not working
        catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            responseMessage = "unreachable";

        }

        catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            responseMessage = "unreachable";

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            responseMessage = "unreachable";

        }

        return responseMessage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        dialog.setProgress((int) (progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //result is the response back from "doInBackground"
        dialog.cancel();

        TextView response_holder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);

        //check if there were errors upoloading
        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("unreachable")) {
            response_holder.setText("Error while uploading...Please check your internet connection and retry.");
            return;
        }

        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("error saving project data")) {
            response_holder.setText("There was an error on the server saving the project data, please retry.");
            return;
        }

        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("error saving sites data")) {
            response_holder.setText("There was an error on the server saving the sites data, please retry.");
            return;
        }

        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("project saved")) {
            response_holder.setText("Data uploaded successfully!");
            return;
        }

        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("project already exist")) {
            response_holder.setText("This project already exist!");
            return;
        }

    }

 }
```

I am guessing it is just calculating the total size of the json string since it is the first part...any suggestions?

Edit: possible duplicate, still with no solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150978/progress-bar-not-update-where-upload-multipart)

Edit: solved adding `totalSize = entity.getContentLength();` before posting the entity, code has been updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this bit of code:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    dialog.setProgress((int) (progress[0]));
}
```

Essentially, you are only caring about the first progress value. That's fine as there is probably only one from your code. But you could publish the progress by adding `publishProgress` statements to your code. This could be done by pushing a percentage each time you are done with something, like this:

```
     int progress_done=20;
     publishProgress(progress_done);
     for (images_cursor.moveToFirst(); !images_cursor.isAfterLast(); images_cursor.moveToNext()) {

            counter++;

            //Get image and convert to byte array
            byte[] image_ba = images_cursor.getBlob(images_cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
            long image_unit_id = images_cursor.getLong(images_cursor.getColumnIndex("unit_id"));
            String image_caption = images_cursor.getString(images_cursor.getColumnIndex("caption"));

            //add image to multipart
            entity.addPart("image" + counter, new ByteArrayBody(image_ba, "image" + counter + ".jpg"));

            //add unit _id to multipart
            entity.addPart("image_unit_id" + counter, new StringBody(String.valueOf(image_unit_id)));

            //add caption to multipart
            entity.addPart("image_caption" + counter, new StringBody(String.valueOf(image_caption)));

            progress_done+=20;
            publishProgress(progress_done);
        }
```

Comment: AsyncTask docs are not the clearest. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)

Comment: Yeah, it took me quite a while to understand how they work. Basically, aSyncTask is meant to operate on a whole host of inputs at the same time. That one piece of key information is missing from the documents so far as I can tell...

Comment: anyway adding that code you suggested did not change anything. I will have another go tomorrow :/

Comment: I suggest you print out what the progress value is, and go from there. Good luck!

Comment: Solved, `totalSize = entity.getContentLength();` was missing, and total size was always 0

Comment: where to put the above statement ? as i have place the code where u said but its still stucks at 100%

Comment: @Hunt: It would be part of your `doInBackground` function.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto but it still stucks at 100%

Comment: i thing use service instead of async is better, mayble i was wrong sorry